# How can I set a selected box values for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for this rather simple question, but I know almost nothing of rails.
What I want to do is that when I'm registering an "Articulo" I would like to choose some default values that they would be given by an attribute of a model, specifically, the attribute "rut_prov" from the model "Proovedor".

This is what I have.

**articulos_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @articulo = Articulo.new
    @proveedors = Proveedor.all
    respond_with(@articulo)
  end
```

**articulos/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">

<h1>Nuevo artículo de venta</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

**articulos/_form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rut_del_proveedor %><br>
    <%= f.select :rut_prov, @proveedors, :class => 'genForm_dropBox' %>
  </div>
```

**view**

[image]

So, I know the problem is `<%= f.select :rut_prov, @proveedors, :class => 'genForm_dropBox' %>`, but I don't know how to make appear as options the values of "rut_prov" of the records I have registered of the model "Proovedor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) method. The following example displays the result of `rut_prov` method call on view and passes `rut_prov` of selected as param:

```
<%= f.collection_select :rut_prov, @proveedors, :rut_prov, :rut_prov, class: 'getForm_dropBox' %>
```

BTW, I **strongly** recommend using English variables/classes/methods names. So it should be `Provider` instead of `Provedoor`, `Article` instead of `Articulo` etc.

Comment: It works fine now , but apparently when I register an article the value of "rut_prov" which is saved is the id of Proveedor or the place in which he appear in the dropbox, I'm not sure, but I'm sure it's not the value of "rut_prov".

**PS**: Yeah,thanks for the suggestion about the language, but I think it's a little late to be changing everything.

Comment: @cursillosonline oh, I thought you wanted ID, if you want `rut_prov` as value (not only description), you should substitude `:id` with `rut_prov`.